# MPAndroidChart No Data Available and No PieChartDrawn

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am trying to us the @MPAndroidChartLibrary to draw some PieCharts in a GridFragment but I keep getting a "No Data Available" Message without rendering any chart.
I would really appreciate some help reviewing the code below. That is what am using to create the PieCharts.

[Screen Capture][1]

```
package utils;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;
import android.text.style.RelativeSizeSpan;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import models.News;

/**
 * Created by Olaolu.Ajose on 14/07/2016.
 */
public class ResultHelper {
    static ArrayList < PieChart > mPieChartList;
    static Context mContext;

    public static ArrayList < PieChart > PieChartExtractor(Context context) {
        mPieChartList = new ArrayList < > ();
        mContext = context;
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                PieChart chart = getPieChart(mContext);
                mPieChartList.add(chart);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return mPieChartList;
        }
        return mPieChartList;
    }

    private static PieChart getPieChart(Context context) {

        PieChart mChart = new PieChart(context);
        mChart.setDescription("");
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "OpenSans-Light.ttf");

        mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(tf);
        mChart.setCenterText(generateCenterText());
        mChart.setCenterTextSize(10 f);
        mChart.setCenterTextTypeface(tf);

        // radius of the center hole in percent of maximum radius
        mChart.setHoleRadius(45 f);
        mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(50 f);

        // radius of the center hole in percent of maximum radius
        mChart.setHoleRadius(45 f);
        mChart.setTransparentCircleRadius(50 f);

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setPosition(Legend.LegendPosition.RIGHT_OF_CHART);

        mChart.setData(generatePieData());
        mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return mChart;
    }

    protected static PieData generatePieData() {

        int count = 4;

        ArrayList < Entry > entries1 = new ArrayList < Entry > ();
        ArrayList < String > xVals = new ArrayList < String > ();

        xVals.add("Quarter 1");
        xVals.add("Quarter 2");
        xVals.add("Quarter 3");
        xVals.add("Quarter 4");

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            xVals.add("entry" + (i + 1));

            entries1.add(new Entry((float)(Math.random() * 60) + 40, i));
        }

        PieDataSet ds1 = new PieDataSet(entries1, "Quarterly Revenues 2015");
        ds1.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
        ds1.setSliceSpace(2 f);
        ds1.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        ds1.setValueTextSize(12 f);

        PieData d = new PieData(xVals, ds1);

        return d;
    }

    private static SpannableString generateCenterText() {
        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Revenues\nQuarters 2015");
        s.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2 f), 0, 8, 0);
        s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GRAY), 8, s.length(), 0);
        return s;
    }

}
```

//Here is My Recycler where the PieCharts are been used.

```
package com.echessa.designdemo.QuizRecyclers;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.graphics.Color;
  import android.support.v4.view.MotionEventCompat;
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.MotionEvent;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;

  import com.echessa.designdemo.R;
  import com.echessa.designdemo.helper.ItemTouchHelperViewHolder;
  import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;

  import java.util.List;

  import utils.ResultHelper;


  public class ResultBoardRecyclerAdapter extends         RecyclerView.Adapter<ResultBoardRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

     private List<PieChart> mPieCharts;
      static Context mContext;
     static List <PieChart> pieChartList;

public ResultBoardRecyclerAdapter(List<PieChart> pieChartItems) {
    mPieCharts = pieChartItems;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.piechart_item, viewGroup, false);
    mContext = v.getContext();
    return  new ViewHolder(v);
}

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.mPieChart = GetResults().get(i);
    viewHolder.mPieChart.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event) == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
 private static List<PieChart> GetResults() {
    if(pieChartList != null){
        return pieChartList;
    }
    List <PieChart> pieChartList =  ResultHelper.PieChartExtractor(mContext);
    return pieChartList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mPieCharts.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
        ItemTouchHelperViewHolder {

    private PieChart mPieChart;

    ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        mPieChart = (PieChart)v.findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected() {
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClear() {
        itemView.setBackgroundColor(0);
    }
}
```

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

New Screen Shot after using this method to add the chart.(viewHolder.mPieChart.addView(GetResults().get(i));)

[Screen shot after refactoring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fArGD.jpg)

Final Screenshot after the fix.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
        android:id="@+id/pieChart"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

[After all said and done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYonk.jpg)

Comment: You need to call `invalidate` on your `PieChart` after setting the data, or else it will not render.

Comment: Hi @Larry I actually did but it didn't work i changed it to  mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();  this also didn't work :(

Comment: How exactly are you using those `PieChart`s in your layout? If you could post that part of your code it would be appreciated.

Comment: @TR4Android, please let me know if you need any other code snippet.
Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of your issue is that the `PieChart`s displayed in your list are ***not*** the ones your are creating in your `PieChartExtractor` method. Instead they are the default ones defined in your layout file, without any data.

You need to actually add the `PieChart` to the view, just setting the `mPieChart` object to the required one won't work. Give the root `LinearLayout` an id and load it in your `ViewHolder` constructor to a variable named `mRootLayout`, then do:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.mRootLayout.removeAllViews();
    viewHolder.mRootLayout.addView(GetResults().get(i));
    // ...
}
```

Generally though, I'd suggest you only create the `PieData` in your extractor and then set the appropiate data to your `PieChart` as this will allow you to recycle the `PieChart`s.

Comment: Thank you very much @TR4Android. 

viewHolder.mPieChart.addView(GetResults().get(i)); -- Worked!

viewHolder.mPieChart = GetResults().get(i); Didn't Work which was what was implemented before.

the other challenge now is i cant see any chart but can see the detials and descriptions. :(

Comment: I have added the new screenshot

Comment: This is probably because your charts are too small to properly display the pies.

Comment: @Olaolu Ajose Good to see that it’s working now! :) If you'd kindly accept the answer so it won't appear in the list of unanswered questions that'd be great.